# How to route Overidden Get methods in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, routes

there is a **TaskController : ApiController**
which contains 2 **Get** methods

```
public string Get(string cNumber){...}

public string Get(string task, string eNumber, string cNumber){...}
```

Configs are by defualt

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes
                .Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

The first **GET** should be called like

```
http://localhost:50159/api/task?cnumber=123456
```

The second **GET** should be called like

```
http://localhost:50159/api/task?enumber=42&cnumber=123456
```

The issue is that always the first **GET** called.
Could somebody explain me why and how to fix it?

P.s. it is basically the first time when I work with asp.net MVC so remember that fact please when you will answer or asked me additional questions.

Comment: try it http://localhost:50159/api/task/Get?enumber=42&cnumber=123456

Answer (score 0):

try like this ,it will fix your issue

```
    [HttpGet("cnumber")]
    public string Get(string cNumber){...}

    [HttpGet("eNumber")]
    public string Get(string task, string eNumber, string cNumber){...}
```

and while calling that api from postman use api/Task/cnumber and api/Task/enumber respectively.

By using this way ,you can create as many get() method you want.

just provide route to that get() method as per above code